# Nginx try_files not working for default index.html

Tags: nginx, devops, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using $geoip_country_code module of nginx to redirect user based on IP. My config code is as given below-

```
server {
      listen 80;
      gzip on;
      server_name example.com;
      root html/example;
      location / {
        index index.html;
        try_files /$geoip_country_code/index.html /index.html;
      }
      location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$ { }
  }
```

Idea is to redirect the user based on country for which I have localised otherwise the user goes to default index i.e generic for everyone else. It works perfectly when opened in browser from my country as I have localised for it. But when opened from a different country it shows internal server error. Its not going to default index page.

Can someone point me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the logs that you see in the nginx access/error logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last element of the `try_files` statement is the default action, which is either a URI or a response code. The `/index.html` starts a search for a new `location` to process the request, and ends up back at the start, so you have a redirection loop.

You can fix the problem by making `/index.html` a **file** term instead. For example:

```
try_files /$geoip_country_code/index.html /index.html =404;
```

The `=404` is never actioned, because `/index.html` always exists.

Personally, I would use a generic solution:

```
try_files /$geoip_country_code$uri $uri /index.html;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: Nnginx is driving me nuts. It returns 404 when `/index.html` clearly exists, and outputs nothing in the error log. How exactly do you "make `/index.html` a **file** term instead"? The OP already had `try_files /$geoip_country_code/index.html /index.html;`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Read the linked document. You will see that `try_files` accepts one or more *file* parameters which are processed within the same `location` block, but the **last** parameter is either a response code, named location or an internal URI. In the case of a URI, which looks the same as a file term, but causes Nginx to restart the search for a matching `location`. The problem with the OP was that the `try_files` statement caused a redirection loop.